# How to change Kibana-4's default Time Filter?

Tags: kibana-4

I have created a dashboard in Kibana-4 and shared on my Web-app. But its default time filter is 15 minutes.
How to change the default time filter in kibana-4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The time-filter is not saved as part of the dashboard, and shouldn't be in my opinion. A dashboard shows you the data organized in a certain kind of way, and each user should be able to modify the date-range of their view however they see fit.

If you're interested in changing the kibana default, you can do so by modifying the code.
Go to the file 'services/timefilter.js', and there is a variable called `timeDefaults`. You can modify it to match the default value you're interested in.

In the code it looks like this:

```
var timeDefaults = {
    from: 'now-15m',
    to: 'now'
};
```

The `from` and `to` properties are parsed using **ISO8601** format.

Comment: In kibana 4.0.2, timeDefaults is located in src\public\index.js

Comment: In kibana 4.6, it's under /src/ui/public/config/defaults.js
Or via the dashboard "Settings >> Advanced" and search for timeDefaults

Comment: In Kibana 7.4 or maybe even earlier @sid8491 solution is more convenient.

Answer (score 15):

In 4.5.0, you should be able to change it anytime in the Kibana ui by navigating to "Settings"->"Advanced". See this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html). Just edit the `timepicker:timeDefaults` to something like `{ "from": "now-90d", "to": "now", "mode": "quick" }`

Comment: worked for me!  too set the default to "past 2 years" its...   `{ "from": "now-2y", "to": "now", "mode": "quick" }`

Answer (score 9):

You can preset time filter in dashboard link. For example setting to last 6 hours:

```
kibana-host:5601/#/dashboard/My-Dashboard?_g=(time:(from:now-6h,mode:quick,to:now))
```

Comment: This is helpful if you don't want to change Kibana index.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

At least as of Kibana version 7.4, and possibly for earlier releases as well:

From the left menu click on `Management`, then select `Advanced Settings` from the Kibana top menu.

Here you can change the defaults of a Kibana dashboard.

Search for `timepicker:timeDefaults` and click on edit and change the `from` value from `now-15m` to the value you want to set, using `s` for seconds, `m` for minutes, `h` for hours, `w` for weeks, `M` for months, `d` for days, or `y` for years.

I wanted to see data of past 2 years so I have set it as
`{
  "from": "now-2y",
  "to": "now",
  "mode": "quick"
}`

Finally, click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button to the right of the edited field:[image: Time filter defaults]

Hope it helps.